# Can python optimize a variable to get max Pearson's correlation coefficient?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

If I have pandas dataframe includes 3 columns `Col1` & `Col2`& `Col3` and I need to get max Pearson's correlation coefficient between `Col2` and `Col3` By considering the values in `Col1` where the modified values For `Col2` obtained by the next formula:

```
df['Col1']=np.power((df['Col1']),B)
df['Col2']=df['Col2']*df['Col1']
```

where B is the changing variable to get max  Pearson's correlation coefficient between `Col3` and the new values of `Col2`

So is there a Python method that can do that and return B.Is there a way to do this operation using Python and return B value, where I want to repeat this process to other columns.

Comment: What are the bounds on `B`?

Comment: not bounds for B values just give an initial value for it

Comment: And where is `col3` getting modified? (since you mentioned new values of 'col2' and 'col3')

Comment: Col3 did not modify the Col2 that modified firstly based on the intial value of B. Sorry for causing misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# dataframe with 20 rows
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(20,3), 
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

# cost function
def cost_fun(B_array, df):
    B = B_array[0]
    new_col1 = np.power((df['Col1']), B)
    new_col2 = np.array(df['Col2']) * new_col1
    col3 = np.array(df['Col3'])
    pearson = np.corrcoef(new_col2, col3)[1,0]
    return -1*pearson # multiply by -1 to get max

# initial value
B_0 = 1.1

# run minimizer
res = minimize(cost_fun, [B_0], args=(df), 
               options={"maxiter": 100,
                        "disp": True})
# results
print(res)
```

Comment: why you use this line return `-1*pearson # multiply by -1 to get max`, is the best to use abs (np.corrcoef(new_col2, col3)[1,0])?

Comment: `minimize` tries to get the lowest possible objective function value. Since the goal is to maximize the pearson, we try to minimize the negative of it. We are not trying to get the absolute value