# Optimize changing variables to get max Pearson's correlation coefficient for multiple columns

Tags: python, scipy, correlation, minimization, scipy-optimize

Amendment:

If I have a pandas DataFrame that includes 5 columns `Col1` & `Col2` & `Col3` & `Col4` & `Col5` and I need to get max Pearson's correlation coefficient between(`Col2`,`Col3`) & (`Col2`,`Col4`) & (`Col2`,`Col5`) by considering the values in `Col1`

The modified values for `Col2` which obtained by the next formula:

```
df['Col1']=np.power((df['Col1']),B)
df['Col2']=df['Col2']*df['Col1']
```

where  `B` is the changing variable (a single value) to get max Pearson's correlation coefficient between (new values of `Col2`,`Col3`) & (new values of `Col2`,`Col4`) & (new values of `Col2`,`Col5`).

Update:

[image]

The above table containing 5 columns as I mentioned above, the correlation between coefficient between (`Col2`,`Col3`) & (`Col2`,`Col4`) & (`Col2`,`Col5`) is illustrated below the table.

I need to change the values of `Col2` based on two the mentioned equations where the changing value is `B`.

So the question is how to get the best value of `B` that gives a new correlation coefficient greater than or equal its counterpart(old)?

[image]

Update 2 :

Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5

2,0.051361397,2618,1453,1099

4,0.053507779,306,153,150

2,0.041236151,39,54,34

6,0.094526419,2755,2209,1947

4,0.079773397,2313,1261,1022

4,0.083891415,3528,2502,2029

6,0.090737243,3594,2781,2508

2,0.069552772,370,234,246

2,0.052401789,690,402,280

2,0.039930675,1218,846,631

4,0.065952096,1706,523,453

2,0.053064126,314,197,123

6,0.076847486,4019,1675,1452

2,0.044881545,604,402,356

2,0.073102611,2214,1263,1050

0,0.046998526,938,648,572

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example dataframe?

Comment: @Cleb Can you check the updates?

Comment: Could you add data one can copy&paste? Images don't help much...

Comment: @Cleb This is OK?

Comment: Yes, for those interested, you can use `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not extremely elegant, but works; feel free to make this more generic:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def minimize_me(b, df):

    # we want to maximize, so we have to multiply by -1
    return -1 * df['Col3'].corr(df['Col2'] * df['Col1'] ** b )

# read your dataframe from somehwere, e.g. csv
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

# B is greater than 0 for now
bnds = [(0, None)]

res = minimize(minimize_me, (1), args=(df,), bounds=bnds)

if res.success:
    # that's the optimal B
    print(res.x[0])

    # that's the highest correlation you can get
    print(-1 * res.fun)
else:
    print("Sorry, the optimization was not successful. Try with another initial"
          " guess or optimization method")
```

This will print:

```
0.9020784246026575 # your B
0.7614993786787415 # highest correlation for corr(col2, col3)
```

I now read from `clipboard`, replace that by your `.csv` file. You should then also avoid the hardcoding of the columns; the code above is just for demonstration purposes, so that you see how to set up the optimization problem itself.

If you are interested in the sum, you can use (rest of code unmodified):

```
def minimize_me(b, df):

    col_mod = df['Col2'] * df['Col1'] ** b

    # we want to maximize, so we have to multiply by -1
    return -1 * (df['Col3'].corr(col_mod) +
                 df['Col4'].corr(col_mod) +
                 df['Col5'].corr(col_mod))
```

This will print:

```
1.0452394748131613
2.3428368479642137
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I need single value for B can give the max correlation tho output of your code is the same in the accepted answer in this question '[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868595/can-python-optimize-a-variable-to-get-max-pearsons-correlation-coefficient )'

Comment: @Sidhom: What do you mean by single value? Should `B` maximize the sum of correlation coefficients of `col2, col3`, `col2, col4` and `col2, col5`?

Comment: I mean the output of B should be one value can give the best correlation between the mentioned pairs together. If not there a python method can do that I think your idea about maximizing the sum  of correlation coefficients of `col2, col3`, `col2, col4` and `col2, col5`  will be enough

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is the better way to achieve the required.